# How to add an event with clickable location using facebook's graph api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

As per title, I'm able to get the textual representation, but is there a way to have it clickable as it would be if we were adding an event location that exists on fb (has a page)?

I'm using the php-sdk. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have also struggled with this behaviour - even locations with complete and correct addresses do not display the location map.  What we have found is that we can edit the Event and save the Event (without any changes) and the map will then display.  This appears to be related to when the lat\long are calculated (or not calculated).

Comment: Thanks, after your comment I tried to send latitude and longitude along with an event, but it did not change anything.Going directly to facebook is not an option for me as I'm updating multiple channels at the same time.

Comment: Found this bug report on FB https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173095916131752 which may mean that as soon as lat/long data is taken into account it might be possible to add venue names with a map.